# JAX-RS: Is there a serializer for json for root element, part of a list, param in Web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs

At the moment I'm designing a RESTful API and use JAX-RS for the backend. Many reponses have the following simple form:

```
{
  "someList": [
    "item1" : ...,
    "item2" : ...,
    "itemn" : ...
  ]
}
```

The important thing is the field name of the array. It's required by the client (EmberJS Data). I try to create the responses with the standard ResponseBuilder, but I don't know how to define a field name for the list. All responses I get look like:

```
[
  "item1" : ...,
  "item2" : ...,
  "itemn" : ...
]
```

In the past I just always created a container class with one property for the list. That works, but I think there must be a better solution. Maybe a helper class to envelope other objects?

Answer (score 3):

This is depending on the JSON-Serializer you are using. [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) is wrapping the response in a root-element per default (I don’t think EnvelopeObject is a correct word for this).

If you are using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) you can configure this behavior with [SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE) (or DeserializationFeature).

The name of the key can be specified with [@JsonRootName](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) if you are using Jackson-Annotations or [@XmlRootElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html) if you are using JAXB-Annotations.